# what is the result in OCPJP certification

Tags: java

According to the OCPJP certification the following 3 lines of code compile accordingly:

```
 a- public static void main(String...a) {
 b- public static void main(String... a) {
 c- public static void main(String[]... a) {
```

However when I try to implement this in Eclipse the third line of code doesn't run, does anyone know why?

Thanks cordially

Comment: Works for me, no idea what you're talking about. What error do you get?

Comment: Yeah obviously it'll work fine!

Answer (score 1):

All three methods compile but the third one will not *run* as the `main` entry point method for your program since it doesn't have `main`'s signature.

Answer (score 0):

The third one is a valid method, but you need a correct main method to run your program. Then

```
c - public static void main(String[]... a) {
```

will be overloading *main()* method.